# An example of Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue problem

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm not sure if this has been asked before but I couldn't find it.

I want to solve the Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue problem
$$ u''+\lambda u=0,\ \ u'(0)=u(1)=0.$$
Let the SL differential operator be $Lu=u''.$ I want to find the eigenvalues/functions of $L$ by solving the boundary value ODE. (Hint: The solution of the ODE is

$$ u(x)=\lambda\int_0^1 g(x,s)u(s)ds$$
where $g(x,s)=
     \begin{cases} 
         s(1-x),\ 0\leq s\leq x\leq 1\\
         x(1-s),\ 0\leq x\leq s\leq 1
     \end{cases}.$)

Here's my solution. 
To solve the ODE, let $u''=\frac{\partial u' }{\partial x}$. Then
$$ \int \partial u' = -\lambda \int u(t) \partial t$$
$$ u'(x)  = -\lambda \int_a^x u(t) \partial t + c_1$$
Now, let $u'(x) = \frac{\partial u(x) }{\partial x}$. Then,
$$\int \partial u(x) = \int^x_b \big( -\lambda \int^x_a  u(t) \partial t + c_1\big)\ dx  $$
$$ u(x) =-\lambda \int^x_b \big( \int^x_a  u(t) \partial t + c_1\big)\ dx +c_2$$
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler approach.

The general solution for the DE $u''+\lambda u = 0$ is

$$
u = c_1\sin(\sqrt \lambda t)+c_2\cos(\sqrt\lambda t)
$$

the boundary conditions are

$$
\cases{u'(0) = \sqrt\lambda c_1\cos(\sqrt\lambda 0)-\sqrt\lambda c_2\sin(\sqrt\lambda 0) = 0\\
u(1) = c_1\sin(\sqrt \lambda)+c_2\cos(\sqrt\lambda) = 0}
$$

or

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\ \sin(\sqrt\lambda) & \cos(\sqrt\lambda)\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}c_1\\ c_2\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}0\\ 0\end{array}\right)
$$

now to have non trivial solutions we need $\cos(\sqrt\lambda) = 0$ or

$$
\sqrt\lambda = (2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

then the eigenvalues are

$$
\lambda_k =  \left((2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2
$$

and the eigenfunctions are

$$
u_k = \cos\left((2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}t\right)
$$

Those eigenfunctions  can be used to solve non-homogeneous problems with the same boundary conditions.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where I can find how to derive the general solution to the DE?

Comment: With the Laplace transform we have $$(s^2+\lambda)U(s) = s c_1 + c_2$$ so $$U(s) = \frac{s c_1}{s^2+\lambda}+ \frac{c_2}{s^2+\lambda}$$ and after inversion we have $$u(t) = c_1\cos(\sqrt\lambda t)+c_2\sin(\sqrt\lambda t)$$

Comment: Is $c_1=u(0)$ and $c_2=u'(0)$?

Comment: Also, how do you know $\lambda\geq 0$?

Comment: Also, I think there's a negative sign missing from the eigvalues!

Comment: When using the Laplace transform, $c_1, c_2$ generally are associated to the initial values but can be also considered as integration constants as was done. If $\lambda\lt 0$ then the equation should be $u''-\lambda u = 0$ and the eigen functions hyperbolic functions.

Comment: Thank you. Since $Lu=u''=-\lambda u$, shouldn't $-\lambda_k'$s be the eigenvalues?

Comment: Here $L = -\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$.